# Linux to authenticate using MS AD using samba

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012, samba

I am trying to complete a poc which needs linux server to connect to MS AD and authenticate using domain creds. After some reference, I felt samba would do good here and so I have installed and configured samba on the linux server.

Whenever I do net ads join -U administrator, it throws the following error.

```
Host is not configured as a member server.
Invalid configuration.  Exiting....
Failed to join domain: This operation is only allowed for the PDC of the domain.
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Which Samba version? 3 and 4 do differ significantly. Also, are you planning to *provide* file services on your Linux server or do you just need to access SMB shares of Windows Servers?

Comment: @the-wabbit: I just need to authenticate users based on our existing windows AD.

Answer (score 2):

Some month ago I tried to solve this problem - it was a nightmare...
Yesterday, I started again to try to join Linux to the Domain Controller - and following the steps described here:
http://koo.fi/blog/2015/06/16/ubuntu-14-04-active-directory-authentication/
worked perfectly. After those steps, Linux was able to authenticate all AD Users :-)

Comment: Thanks. But I am getting this error when I try to login as admin.

kinit: Cannot find KDC for realm "<Domain>" while getting initial credentials

Even I am not able to ping the domain, but I can ping the internal ip of DC. What might be the issue.?

Comment: @serverstackqns this sounds like your /etc/krb5.conf is not matching your environment. You should add some information about your domain and configuration to the question.

Comment: @serverstackqns: I followed the linked description (including the prerequisites setting dns & time source) and the described sssd installation did everything: most config-files were automagically changed and I had just to change the descibed files manually.
I tried to fix the problems of my old machine, but after 1 or 2 days I started with a new installation - and it was done in 1 or 2 hours :-)